# How to use default Windows driver for sound card? - Windows 10 auto-update

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10. In 8.1 I used default system driver for sound card in my Toshiba Portege Z30 (it has different settings for headphones/speakers)

But Windows 10 always automatically instals Realtek High Definition Audio. I can delete it all day, it always comes back even though default driver works fine as in 8.1.

I tried the tool to hide this update, it did not help.

Is there any way how can I keep the default driver? Disabling Realtek in Device Manager did not help - I am left without sound.

Thanks, this is driving me crazy.

EDIT: Disabled installing driver software via Windows Update, but it still instals "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. - Audio Device, Other hardware - Realtek High Definition Audio" and requiers restart.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Control Panel>System>Advanced system settings>Hardware tab>Device Installation Settings button

tick "never install driver software from Windows Updates"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems like solution.. However this will cause problems when I plug any new hardware right?

Comment: I assume so, I never trusted Windows update for drivers, too may blue screens and other serious issues. I always download them from the manufacturer and install at my convenience.

Comment: You can probably still use the "old school" driver wizard to obtain drivers from Windows Update, on demand-ish.

Comment: Looks like this did not help :/ Windows Update today installed "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. - Audio Device, Other hardware - Realtek High Definition Audio" and wants PC restart.

Comment: WTF Microsoft, what is that setting for then, I hope W10 bombs worse than Vista did.